# How to stretch image to fit the size of stage in Vue Konva?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, konvajs

I am working with a konva.js. I have a stage that has a image inside it. But when I resize the stage, the image will be cropped and I can't see full image. Is there a way to stretch the image to fit it inside the stage and still get a full image.

```
     <template>
      <div class="konvaContainer">
          <v-stage :config="stageConfig" >
            <v-layer>
              <v-image :config="imageConfig1"/>
            </v-layer>
          </v-stage>
        </div>
     </template>

     export default {
       components: {
         Loading},
       data: () => ({
       stageConfig: {width: 200,height:150 },
       imageConfig: {},
       scaleValue:1
       })}
```

And also can we set new value to the scaleValue or replace the value of scaleValue with new value?

Comment: Set the width and height of the image to the bounds of the stage.  But the image may look stretched if the aspect ratio of stage and image differ.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the size of the image to the same size as the stage.

```js
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <v-stage ref="stage" :config="stageSize">
      <v-layer>
        <v-image
          :config="{
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            width: stageSize.width,
            height: stageSize.height,
            image: image,
          }"
        />
      </v-layer>
    </v-stage>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
</style>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      stageSize: {
        width: 10,
        height: 10,
      },
      image: null,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    // setup resize
    const container = document.querySelector(".container");
    const observer = new ResizeObserver(() => {
      this.stageSize.width = container.offsetWidth;
      this.stageSize.height = container.offsetHeight;
    });
    observer.observe(container);

    // load image
    const img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "https://i.imgur.com/ktWThtZ.png";
    img.onload = () => {
      this.image = img;
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-konva-stretch-image-to-stage-size-7ql7l?file=/src/App.vue